# Battery issues: Should I wait or get my laptop replaced?

Tags: laptop, battery

I bought a new laptop which has a 10 day replacement policy on it. The laptop has battery issues -- for example, Windows always says that the laptop has 0% battery and that it's not charging (and Endless OS is unable to read the battery percentage) and the laptop seems to switching off randomly (it's a Acer Swift 3).  When I saw that, I ordered a replacement. A technician will visit in a week to authorize the replacement.

Meanwhile, I saw today morning that the laptop's battery indicators (Windows) are now working (although I'm yet to see if they're good enough). I'm now draining the battery and charging it back up to see if it's alright.

Should I wait to see if the battery works? And if it works properly in the time the technician comes to visit, should I cancel the replacement? Is it a temporary battery calibration issue or do you think it's a more permanent battery (hardware) issue that might crop up again sometime later (even if it seems alright now)?

Comment: Its new, you should not have to work on it, get it replaced now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description, there seems to be some problem. If the indicators are working, try a couple of full charge and recharge cycles to make sure that the battery is working properly. In case if the issue comes back, better to get it checked/replaced.

Comment: Thanks. It only worked for a few hours before propping up again. I'm going ahead with the replacement. :)